# Using Javascript, How can I check that a input from a user meets all conditions, then displays an output?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am doing my assignment for making a tool to check whether the year entered by the user is a leap year or not and the year entered has to be greater than 1582. I am still new to JavaScript and I was looking to get some feedback on what I have so far.

**NOTE:** In order for the year to be leap year, it has to be DIVISIBLE BY 4, unless it is also divisible by 100 but not 400. My answer should round to the first decimal place. Example: 5.01 is 5.0

I have tried getting the input year to meet all those conditions but I'm assuming I have not done so in the proper format so I'm looking for some feedback to what I can edit. Thanks in advance

```
<p> Enter a year later than 1582 and we will tell you if it is leap year </p>
<p> Enter your year: </p> <input type="text" id="box6"> <button id="checkyear"> Check Year </button>
<p> Leap year output will appear here: </p> <input type="text" id="box7" disabled style="width:15%;">

let year = document.getElementById("box6")
let yearOutput = document.getElementById("box7")

function leapyear() {
    var inputYear = parseInt(year.value);
    var outputYear = yearOutput;
    if (Number("inputyear") < Number("1582") {
        outputYear.value = inputyear + "is invalid.";
    }
    if (Number("inputYear") > Number("1582") && Number("inputYear") / 4 && 
    Number("inputYear") / 100 && Number("inputYear") / 400 {
        outputYear.value = inputYear + " is a leap year.";
    }
    else if (Number("inputYear") > Number("1582") && 
    Number("inputYear") % 4 !== 0 || Number("inputYear") % 100 !== 0 || Number("inputYear") % 400 !== 0 {
        outputYear.value = inputYear + " is not a leap year."
    }
    else {
        outputYear.value = "Please enter a year to see if it is a leap year or not.";
    }
}
document.getElementById("checkyear").onclick = leapyear;
```

Comment: `Number("inputYear")` attempts to make a number out of the **string** value `"inputYear"`.  You've gotten the value of the `<input>` into the variable `inputYear`, and you've already converted it to a number with `parseInt()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. This is cleaner to me.

```
function leapyear(){
  let inputYear = parseInt(year.value);
  if(inputYear <= 1582){
    outputYear.value = `${inputYear} is invalid.`;
    return;
  }
  if(inputYear % 4 || (!(inputYear % 100) && inputYear % 400)){
    console.log("not leap year");
    outputYear.value = `${inputYear} is not a leap year.`;
    return;
  }
  console.log("leap year");
  outputYear.value = `${inputYear} is a leap year.`;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just started out by checking the value is a number, then used Modulus function. Perfect for this I think % gives us a remainder. Classic use is testing for odd/even [value]%2===0 is even.

```js
let year = document.getElementById("box6");
let yearOutput = document.getElementById("box7");

function leapyear() {
  // Grab our input an convert.
  let inputYear = parseInt(year.value);
  let outputYear = yearOutput;
  // If input year is invalid number OR less than or equal to 1582
  if (isNaN(inputYear) || inputYear <= 1582) {
      outputYear.value = ((isNaN(inputYear)) ? "input" : inputYear) + " is invalid.";
      return;
  }
  
  // lets see if it is a leap (divisible by 4 AND (not 400 and not divisible by 100))
  if(inputYear%4 === 0 && (inputYear === 400 || !inputYear%100 === 0)) {
    console.log("leap year");
    outputYear.value = inputYear + " is a leap year.";
  } else {
    console.log("not leap year");
    outputYear.value = inputYear + " is not a leap year."
  }
}
document.getElementById("checkyear").onclick = leapyear;
```

```html
<p> Enter a year later than 1582 and we will tell you if it is leap year </p>
<p> Enter your year: </p> <input type="text" id="box6"> <button id="checkyear"> Check Year </button>
<p> Leap year output will appear here: </p> <input type="text" id="box7" disabled style="width:15%;">
```

Answer (score 1):

Make your textbox as number instead of text which takes only numeric as valid input.

HTML Code:

```
  <p> Enter a year later than 1582 and we will tell you if it is leap year </p>
   <p> Enter your year: </p> <input type="number" id="box6"> <button id="checkyear"> Check Year </button>
  <p> Leap year output will appear here: </p> <input type="text" id="box7" disabled style="width:15%;">
```

JS Code :

```
 var year = document.getElementById("box6")
 var yearOutput = document.getElementById("box7")
 function checkLeap(){
     var ip = parseInt(year.value);
     if(isNAN(ip) || ip <= 1582){
       yearOutput.value = `${ip} is invalid.`;
      return;
     }
     if(ip % 4 || (!(ip % 100) && ip % 400)){
       yearOutput.value = `${ip} is not a leap year.`;
       return;
     }
    yearOutput.value = `${ip} is a leap year.`;
  }
```